# laravel not loading my form section?

Tags: php, html, laravel

im trying to build a user login and registration form and this is my route :

```
Route::get('/register', function()
{
    return View::make('register');
});

Route::get('/register', function()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();
    $username = Input::get('username');
    return View::make('registered')->with('username',$username);
});
```

and this is my html :

```
<div class="container">
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
<fieldset>
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Appended checkbox -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="appendedcheckbox">  </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="appendedcheckbox" name="appendedcheckbox" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox">
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"> </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-inverse"> </button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
  </div>
```

few problems :

1.
my form does not loads and i see just

the last button for submitting the form and : ' you have registered in $username '  which i design to loads AFTER user submitted

2.my localhost:8000 loaded laravel first page one time but when i began to work on the project i just receiving blank white page and currently accessing my file like this : `http://localhost/vendor/bin/crm/public/register`

3.
is hashing in laravel secure enough? or should i do something else ?

4.
my way of doing this is alright or there is a better way for login and reg using laravel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two routes responding to get requests on `/register`.  Change the second one to `Route::post(...)` and I would also change both to just `register`.  There isn't a need to prepend a slash onto your routes.

Hashing in Laravel is secure and shouldn't be something you have to worry about.

There really isn't a "right" way of doing things, it really depends on how the rest of your app works, how complicated it is, and how easy it should be to maintain.  If it were me though, I would have a LoginController with a method for showing the view and a method for creating the user and have those methods respond to the request rather than putting everything right in your routes.php file.

You are also missing a `{{ Form::close() }}` at the end of your view as well.